# Object.assign returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object, undefined, key-value

Even though a variable (with assigned value: object) is declared in the global scope I'm getting ***undefined***:

[image]

The idea was is to get relevant key/value pairs of revenue, then push it back to the main object(as it doesn't have it by default) in a correct order so revenue[0] pushed to data.results[0] . What am I doing wrong?

```
    //Web-scraping data
    const mainURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=2339027b84839948cd9be5de8b2b36da&language=en-US&sort_by=revenue.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1';
    const movieBaseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/335?api_key=2339027b84839948cd9be5de8b2b36da&language=en-US';
    const apiKey = '2339027b84839948cd9be5de8b2b36da';
    let revenue, data, response, obj;
    let ID_Array = [], keyValueArr = [], allKeyValueArr = [], objectArr = [];
    let text = '';


    //Get main object for d3 visualisation 
    (getMovieList = async() =>{

    try {
        response = await fetch(mainURL);
        data = await response.json();

        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.results[0].title);

        //get movie ID's
        ID_Array = [].concat.apply([], data.results.map(d => d.id))
        console.log(ID_Array);

        getRevenueByID(ID_Array);
        console.trace(getRevenueByID);
        console.table(allKeyValueArr);

        //inject revenue key/value 
       Object.keys(data.results).forEach(key => {
        console.log('The name of the current key: ', key);          
        console.log('The value of the current key: ', data.results[key]);
        data.results[key]['revenue'] = obj;
    });

    console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    })();

    //Retrieve revenue key/value pairs by movie ID's
    getRevenueByID = async (arr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            console.count('Count');
            console.log('ID is: ', arr[i]);

            getRevenueURL = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + arr[i] + '?api_key=' + apiKey + '&language=en-US');
            let data = await getRevenueURL.json();
            console.log('data received: ',data);

            //return key/value array
            keyValueArr = Object.entries(data)[16];
            console.table(keyValueArr);    

            allKeyValueArr.push(keyValueArr);

            //convert key/value array to object
            obj = Object.assign(...allKeyValueArr.map(d => ({[d[0]]: d[1]})));
            console.log('object is: ',obj);
        }
    };
```

Comment: What's the result of `console.log('object is: ',obj);`?

Comment: Does `Object.entries(data)[16]` exist? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you haven't ever assigned value to `obj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await getRevenueByID(ID_Array)` in L:27, otherwise `getMovieList` continues before the additional data is fetched.

After doing so, the result looks like this:
[image]

You probably want this, so you need to change L:35 to `data.results[key]["revenue"] = obj['revenue'];`

[image]

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6zzo9yrz9z

You'll probably want to fetch the additional data into an object and merge it with the initial data later on. That would make the code much more understandable. Assigning to globals from async computations is hard to reason about.

For performance you could run fetching the additional data in parallel for each entry instead, something similar to this:

```
Object.keys(data.results).forEach(key => {
  data.results[key]["revenue"] = getRevenue(key);
});
```

Whether you need to `await getRevenue(key)` depends on how you proceed with the result.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!

Comment: Looks like revenue values are being overwritten from the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Just added three line of changes to solve this. [**My CodePen**](https://codepen.io/aaadesh/pen/LaGLRe?editors=0010)

1. `await` to hold the result in the variable of `async` action.

```
obj = await getRevenueByID(ID_Array);
```

2. Assignment of appropriate value of `revenue` node to the respective result `result object`.

```
data.results[key]['revenue'] = obj[data.results[key].id]['revenue'];
```

2. Assignment respective `revenue` API response against it's `id` node as you are using `for(;;)` loop. Return entire response object to main function.

```
resObj[arr[i]] = obj;

return resObj;
```

Refer my code pen for solution:
https://codepen.io/aaadesh/pen/LaGLRe?editors=0010

**Be careful of global declarations and hoisting effects.**

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you so much Adesh. This helps a lot!